# How to transform number of occurrences to value between 0 and 1?

Tags: data-transformation, terminology

I'm looking for the best statistical practice to transform the number of occurrences (of a word in different documents) into a value between 0 and 1, whereby the first occurrence is worth more than the second, which is worth more than the third, etc. The number of occurrences is theoretically unlimited, so the value should never reach 1.

My approach was to simply use the logarithm. But I don't know how to deal with 0 and 1 and have not yet found a nice way transform the value to a percentage.

Clarification: I have a huge corpus of documents about all kinds of subjects. I want to find the documents that are about, for example, animals' behavior. This will be done with a more complex relevance-check, which doesn't matter at this point. Documents with specific 'interesting terms' in them should have a higher chance to pass the relevance-check.

Example: 'interesting terms': ['cat', 'rat', 'komodowaran', ...]

> document1: "The cat sat on the mat and eyed the rat"

--> 2 Occurrences of 'interesting terms' --> lower the bar for the relevance-check by, e.g., 20%

> document2: "The cat sat on the mat and eyed the rat, but the rat saw the cat and thought 'gosh a cat, I better tell my fellow rats'."

--> 6 Occurrences (after stemming) --> lower the bar for the relevance-check by, e.g., 30%

Beneath a simple and clean approach, I would be grateful for the correct terms to name this problem.

Comment: I don't understand what the data are like here. Logarithm of what precisely? Here's the text of an interesting document: "The cat sat on the mat and eyed the rat". How would this be scored?

Comment: Thanks @NickCox. I edited the question and added an example which hopefully clarifies the problem.

Comment: There are going to be innumerable functions that will map a count in $[0, \infty)\to (0, 1)$. How should we decide which is 'right'?

Comment: @gung Up to the OP to decide which, if any, is useful. As you well know, "all models are wrong..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandora's box type question. The number of answers is as large as desired. Here is one $\sum _{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i=1 - \frac{1}{2^n}$, for which the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty $ is (obviously) 1. The summation can be chosen with different fractions and normalized for a limit of 1. For example, $2 \sum _{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^i$, and in general $(m-1) \sum _{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^i=1 - \frac{1}{m^n}$, where $m-1$ is a positive integer.

In addition, any sum convergent to a non-zero answer can be treated in this same fashion (although to preserve a one-one mapping I would avoid series that have alternating signs, e.g., sub-critically damped sine), such that there are an infinite number of answers.